# How to order posts by meta_value created inside loop?

Tags: loop, order

Inside the `WP_Query`, I'm trying to order posts by price.

The problem is that the price value is not manually defined inside an ACF or so, but it comes from an api call made while looping trough posts, like this:

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ): the_post();

$asin = get_field("asin");?>

<h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
<p><?php echo aawp_get_field_value($asin, 'price'); ?></p>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

That means that the numeric value (the price) isn't available before actually running `$the_query`, so I cannot use something like:

```
'meta_key' => 'price',
'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
'order' => 'ASC'
```

because "price" does not exists at that time.

I searched a lot but I didn't find a solution to this. Maybe I need to order posts after the loop?
How would you do that?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**
(based on shanebp answer)

I made this way.

```
    <?php
 
    $the_query = new WP_Query( array (
        'post_type' => 'prodotto',
        'posts_per_page' => 500,
        'fields' => 'ids',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array (
                'taxonomy' => 'categoria',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'uso-quotidiano',
            )
        ),
    ));

    $items = array();

    $posts = $the_query->posts;

    foreach($posts as $post) {

        $asin = get_field("asin");
        $price = aawp_get_field_value($asin, 'price');

        // refining price value
        $price = str_replace(',', '.', $price);
        $price = preg_replace("/[^0-9\.]/", "", $price);
        $price = (float)$price;

        $items[] = array("id"=>get_the_ID(), "price"=>$price);
    }


    // sorting (asc)
    usort($items, function ($item1, $item2) {
        return $item1['price'] <=> $item2['price'];
    });

    // OUTPUT
    echo '<section class="suggested_product_card_container">';

    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $itemPrice = $item['price'];
        if ($itemPrice < 29) {
              $itemID = $item['id'];
              include(locate_template('/template-parts/components/component-suggested-product-card.php'));
        }
    }

    echo '</section>';

    wp_reset_postdata();

    ?>
```

Comment: What is the implementation of `aawp_get_field_value`? For help with AAWP you should contact AAWP support https://getaawp.com/ 3rd party plugin dev support is off topic here

Comment: moved comment below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `WP_Query`, only return `ids`.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#return-fields-parameter

Create an empty array, `$myArray = array();`.
Then loop thru the results of the query, `$your_query->posts` and fetch your field value for each id and add the result and the id to a new array in `$myArray`.

Then sort the arrays in `$myArray` by the price.

Then do a loop thru `$myArray` to output the display you want for each post id.

Comment: Thanks @shanebp, you put me in the right way. I edited my question with my implementation of the solution you suggested. Take a look at it if you want, and let me know what you think.

Comment: Nice. But you shouldn't need `get_the_ID()`.  The value of `$post` should be the `ID`.